# Select view from another schema. Without "with grant option"

Tags: oracle, view, administration, sql-grant

I have a view V1 in schema A. And want to select it from schema B. 
view V1 include system dictionaries (dba_objects, sys.$views and others).

Now, I granted privileges by request to my admin.

```
grant select on dba_objects to A
grant select on sys.$views to A
grant select on dba_objects to B
grant select on sys.$views to B
grant select on A.V1 to B
```

But have error: insufficient privileges
I understand, that need option: with grant option

```
grant select on dba_objects to A with grant option
grant select on sys.$views to A with grant option
```

But my administrator can't give with grant option. 
Have any ideas, how to do select to view from another schema without with admin option?

Thanks!

Comment: At the very end you mention `with admin option` - not quite the same thing as `with grant option`. Then - if I understand correctly, the problem is that you, the owner of schema A, cannot grant privileges on the data dictionary objects to B. That is OK - ask the DBA to grant those privileges directly to B. Assuming B needs them to do her job, by selecting from your view, this should be no problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you suggest ask the next grants:
grant select on dba_objects to B
grant select on sys.$views to B
But it doesn't help.

Comment: I can't find "it doesn't help" in the Oracle documentation. Can you please explain what that means? Did your DBA grant those privileges to B already? What happened next? "It doesn't help" doesn't help!

Comment: Yes, this grants are given. The same error - insufficient privileges. 
The request from user_tab_privs: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NSU_f_E7I_W-j9rBhppgIm7hkOIeRh1p

Answer (score 0):

For dictionary objects use `create view` & `public synonym` combination in `sys`, and then you may use it in any ordinary schema :

```
SQL> create or replace view v_objects as select * from dba_objects;
SQL> create or replace synonym v_objects2 for v_objects;
SQL> grant select on v_objects2 to A with grant option;
SQL> conn A/pwdA
SQL> create or replace view v_objectsA as select * from sys.v_objects2;
SQL> conn B/pwdB
SQL> create or replace view v_objectsB as select * from sys.v_objects2;
```

Comment: I've done next (without public) :
create or replace view v_objects as select * from dba_objects;
create or replace synonym v_objects for v_objects;
grant select on v_objects to user2;

And trying to select * from v_objects (by user2)
The error is same:   insufficient privileges

Comment: @АлексейБайдин it's normal without `public` keyword, please include that.

Comment: If I add the keyword public, all users can do select from my synonym. In this case my security department  dosn't allow this method. I need to select from exactly user, and only this user.